# I need an example that use OpenCV to compare between 2 faces (UIimage ) and get distance with IOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage

I working on an ios (objective-c) project and I need to compare between 2 faces (each one is an UIimage)with opencv and to get the distance, I know 2 ways that can do  it  Eigenfaces and Fisherfaces, but I can't find a good example in ios 
Are there any recommendations for good code examples that show how to use Eigenfaces or Fisherfaces in ios?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: yes try this https://github.com/ekurutepe/iOS-OpenCV-FaceRec  and please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with this project iOS-OpenCV-FaceRec 
https://github.com/ekurutepe/iOS-OpenCV-FaceRec

If someone needs help let me know

Comment: Could you please explain how can I compare two faces. I have downloaded the example project. In this only one image is passing